# I am writing this C code for a competitive programming platform and would like to know where can I improve the code to overcome SIGTSTP error?

Tags: c

The code gives a SIGTSTP error, which seems to be a runtime error.
I have tried to overcome it and also made a few changes, but it did not work.
How can I overcome this error and make the code better:

Constraints: 
*1≤T≤100; 
   7≤N≤100; 
   350≤Price[i]≤750*

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
long int t,n,good=0,flag=0;
int j,i,*p;
scanf("%ld",&t);
while(t>0)
{
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    if(n>=7)
    {
       p=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%ld",&p[i]);
       for(i=1;i<n;i++)
       {
           for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
           {
               if(i-j > 0)
               {
                   if (p[i]<p[i-j])
                     flag++;
               }
           }
           if (flag==i)
             good++;
       }
    }
    printf("%ld",good);
    t--;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you submitting the program to an online judging system which enforces constraints such as the maximum amount of CPU it can use?  Is that where the "SIGTSTP error" is coming from?

Comment: You have no control of the array bounds and that's where all bugs come from. What if `n=1` and you do `[n-5]`? Simply single step through the code with your debugger and you'll find trivial stuff like that in no time.

Comment: I don't really know. I was working on codechef and I guess it limits the time appointed to a program.

Comment: I'd guess you need to print a newline after the good value, so maybe the judge code doesn't think you've printed any output. Your code looks like it has OK complexity. I'd be wary of off-by-one errors in your i and j loops (e.g. should they start from 0 not 1? You can process `i - j >= 0` not just `i - j > 0`? But we haven't seen the problem statement) but I can't see any potential out-of-bounds here.

Comment: You're also not resetting the good and flag values between test cases.

Comment: You `malloc()` memory but you never `free()` that memory when no longer needed (e.g., latest at the end of the program).

Comment: Using `%ld` to read `int` value will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` to expose the function prototypes `malloc()`  and `free()`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: The function: `malloc()` 1) is expecting a parameter with type `size_t` (long unsigned int), not long int.  2) the returned type, in C, is `void *` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the cast

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%ld",&p[i]);`  The 'p[1]' is a reference to a 'int*', not a 'long int*'  So the format conversion specifier should be: '%d', not '%ld'